# UTF8 character encoding in Perl DBI, MySQL with ő and ű characters

Tags: mysql, perl, encoding, utf-8, dbi

I'm using hungarian language with nice ő and ű characters in my `perl` script with `DBI` and `MySQL`.  All the database encoding is UTF8, and I use utf8 everywhere. The table is in utf8_general_ci encoding and the rows are too utf8_general_ci.

I was tried to change the table and rows encoding to utf8_hungarian_ci and utf8_unicode_ci. This is not help.

When I was insert the rows using PHPMyAdmin, and it seems everything is okay, and when I check in console there is good too. Only if I try to use in Perl DBI connect, only this case I see '?' characters instead of 'ő', 'Ő', 'ű' and 'Ű' characters.

Here is my perl script:

```
use uft8;
use DBI

my $db = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:dbname=...", "user", "passwd",
                      {mysql_enable_utf8 => 1}) || die $DBI::error;

$db->do("INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ('őűŐŰ')");
my $dbh = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM mytable;");
$dbh->execute;
while (my @this = $dbh->fetchrow_array) {
    print $this[0]."\n";
}
```

What is wrong? Is there a special parameter or setting for DBI? Or

Comment: Run `SET NAMES UTF8`  before inserting

Comment: According to the documentation this should be done by mysql_enable_utf8, but I am no expert in DBI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `mysql_enable_utf8` line, and your script works for me. Also remember to always use `strict` and `warnings`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "dbi:mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host;port=$port;",
    $username,
    $pw,
);
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ('őűŐŰ')");
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name FROM mytable");
$sth->execute;
while(my ($name) = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    print "$name\n"; # őűŐŰ
}
exit;
```

Answer (score 4):

The first thing you should do is identify what is failing. You are printing characters you retrieved from the database after storing them in the database after reading them from the Perl sources. That's four possible steps that could have failed.

1. Does `sprintf "U+%v04x", $sql` include `U+0151.0171.0150.0170`? If so, the query is what you think it is.
2. When you insert them using your script, does the data appear correctly when viewed using phpMyAdmin? If so, the characters were inserted properly.
3. Does `sprintf "U+%v04x", $this[0]` give `U+0151.0171.0150.0170`? If so, the characters were retrieved properly.
4. Then there's just the issue of outputting them correctly. You didn't tell Perl how to encode the string for output.

   ```
   use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF8)';    # Most unix boxes
   use open ':std', ':encoding(cp1252)';  # Most Windows boxes
   ```